# SFTP using Pysftp on Openshift

Tags: openshift, pysftp

I have a django application running on openshift. From the openshift server I move a file from openshift to a private server. I can do this by setting hostkeys to none and using a password, however that password will change every month so I need to use ssh keys.

I have the following on the private server: known_hosts, id_rsa, id_rsa.pub.

When I try to connect from openshift I receive the error "No Known Hostkeys."

I known since this is a dockerized application running on the cloud this might be a bit tricky to answer, but I could really use some help.

Thank you,

I have attempted to put the id_rsa.pub from the private server into a file and use hostkeys.load(id_rsa.pub) and then connect without a password.

Setup
/opt/app-root/src/.ssh/known_hosts - I have the known_hosts from the private server

```
/views.py -
id_rsa_pub = "known_hosts"
        id_rsa_pub = settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0] + '/' + id_rsa_pub
        known_hosts = '/opt/app-root/src/.ssh/known_hosts'
        cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
        print("id_rsa_pub below:")
        print(id_rsa_pub)

        cnopts.hostkeys.load(known_hosts)

        with pysftp.Connection(host=host, username=username, 
        private_key=id_rsa_pub, cnopts=cnopts) as srv:

id_rsa_pub is located in static files
```

The error is "pysftp.exceptions.HostKeysException: No Host Keys Found"

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this was quick.

I never solved the hostkey issue, however if you use private_key=id_rsa_pub and you have a path to it on Openshift in you src somewhere, the connection will go through. Make sure to set cnopts.hostkeys = None.

Thanks